# Building existing sln fails with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csc, visual-studio-2019

I just upgraded to VS2019 and am unable to build an existing solution. The Compiler generates the following error on some of the projects within the solution:

> The "DisableSdkPath" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check if you are using the [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) package. Upgrading to Version 3.0.0 resolved the issue on my side.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for sharing your solution here. You can mark it as answer to make this solution easier to find.

Comment: This wasn't the exact answer, but deleting this section from the .csproj file did the trick. Somehow it got in there over the years, but was unused.

Comment: So, what would've been an exact(lier) answer? Might want to share your insights?

Comment: Close visual studio and again open project from Visual studio works for me!